# Sharepoint Online, Javascript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Making a SharePoint app using JavaScript to manage the data level.

This works find in IE and Chrome but dose nothing in Firefox, no errors no warnings just no action!

```
function List_AddCompany() {
    var ListName = "CompanyInfo";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var lstObject = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = lstObject.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
        newItem.set_item('CPY_ID', $('#CPY_ID').text());
        newItem.set_item('CPY_Name', $('#CPY_Name').val());
        newItem.set_item('CPY_OverDuePercentage', $('#CPY_OverDuePercentage').val());

    newItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, onFailure));

    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("Company added successfully");
    }

    function onFailure(sender, args) {
        console.log("There was an error creating company", args);
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be great

Comment: Cache ? Maybe you have previously loaded the page inside firefox and now the browser seen the old one. Try to clean Firefox cache or Press Ctrl+F5 on page or Launch the Firefox in incognito..

Comment: Afraid not, I have a feeling it is around how firefox is dealing with the executeQueryAsync command as it does hit a break point at either onSuccess or onFailure

Comment: try `context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all the internal functions as @Vaibhav suggested and this allowed me to see the issue that arose from that when it came to passing variables well.
So to resolve this I wrote a deferred code block to handle all adding and this seems to work across browsers (Even though the MS website says the other way works)

Below is the code for the deferred statement and its usage.

```
function addListItems(listTitle, propertiesToAdd) {
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var newItem = list.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
propertiesToAdd.forEach(function (entry) {
    newItem.set_item(entry.ID, entry.newval);
});
    newItem.update();
var d = $.Deferred();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    d.resolve(true);
},
function (sender, args) {
    d.reject(args);
});
return d.promise();
```

}

And the usage code

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    var listTitle = 'List Name';
    var propertiesToAdd = [];
    propertiesToAdd.push({
        ID: "Property Name",
        newval: Property Value,
    })
    propertiesToAdd.push({
        ID: "Property Name",
        newval: Property Value,
    })
    addListItems(listTitle, propertiesToAdd)
    .done(function (items) {
        console.log("added successfully");
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log("There was an error creating company", error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we faced this same issue.
 Fix is to bring *function onSuccess()*  and *function onFailure(sender, args)* outside *function List_AddCompany()*

If you test your current code with debugger with single stepping it after  context.executeQueryAsync debugger will land on failure method and wont go inside the method and will go back to calling function and will end code without any error.

```
function List_AddCompany() {
    var ListName = "CompanyInfo";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var lstObject = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = lstObject.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
    newItem.set_item('CPY_ID', $('#CPY_ID').text());
    newItem.set_item('CPY_Name', $('#CPY_Name').val());
    newItem.set_item('CPY_OverDuePercentage', $('#CPY_OverDuePercentage').val());

    newItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, onFailure));
}

function onSuccess() {
    console.log("Company added successfully");
}

function onFailure(sender, args) {
    console.log("There was an error creating company", args);
}
```

Comment: This is very much along the lines of what I suspected. Will test tonight. Thanks

Comment: So I have to give you a little thumbs up, but it still didn't solve me issue so I went for a big re-write of all my add functions.